# Variable Not Working With Glob Function In Php

Tags: php

```
foreach(glob($select)) as $filename){
    echo $filename;
    echo "<a class='vlightbox1' href='$filename' title='$filename'><img src='$filename' style='height:120px; width:160px; alt='$filename'></a>";
    echo "<a href='ap_deleteimages.php?id=$filename'>Delete</a>";
}
```

It is not working Properly. I Have Added `$select` Value as under

```
$select=document.write(document.getElementById('flist').value)
```

and 'flist' is a option tag id in html and glob function do not work with it

Comment: "Not working" is not an error message I ever heard of.

Comment: There is definitely syntax error. 1 opening '(' against 3 closing ')'

Comment: You are missing lot of things

Comment: please put proper question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(glob($select) as $filename){
    echo $filename;
    echo "<a class='vlightbox1' href='$filename' title='$filename'><img src='$filename' style='height:120px; width:160px; alt='$filename'></a>";
    echo "<a href='ap_deleteimages.php?id=$filename'>Delete</a>";
}
```

You have the syntax error at glob function in your code. The right syntax is in above code.

Second thing is that `glob()` is used to find all the search pathname matching a pattern. So you need to check that the value of `$select` is correct or not.

Read more above [`glob()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

Comment: foreach(glob($select) as $filename){
    echo $filename;
    echo "<a class='vlightbox1' href='$filename' title='$filename'><img src='$filename' style='height:120px; width:160px; alt='$filename'></a>";
    echo "<a href='ap_deleteimages.php?id=$filename'>Delete</a>";
} still not working because I used $select=<script>document.write(document.getElementById('flist').value)</script>

Comment: Your this line `$select=<script>document.write(document.getElementById('flist').value)</script>` is incorrect.

Comment: what?? is mistake here

Comment: @DeepParmar You are assigning the value in PHP variable from javascript and you should know that PHP execute on server side and javascript on client side so it is not possible.

Comment: when i echo that value it give me perfectly path but in glob function it not working

Comment: i show you code + output with comments

Comment: <?php
$select="<script>document.write(document.getElementById('flist').value)</script>‌​";
echo $select;            //user_files/one/*.*‌​
foreach(glob($select) as $filename){
     echo "<a class='vlightbox1' href='$filename' title='$filename'><img src='$filename' style='height:120px; width:160px; alt='$filename'></a>";
     echo "<a href='ap_deleteimages.php?id=$filename'>Delete</a>";
}
?>

Comment: @DeepParmar `echo $select;`  what is returning.

Comment: its done i have passed value through javascript to php , but tnx for ur help

Comment: @DeepParmar great for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting in the parentheses?

```
foreach ( glob($select) as $filename)
```